# How to print this string in C when I have the pointer to it?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I'm a Java dev and I'm learning C and I want to print a `string`, and it's not working. I see that is very hard to print a `string` in C compared to Java.

This is the code:

```
static struct t_node* create_tnode(char* n) {
        // Assigning memory to struct variable temp
        struct t_node *temp=(struct t_node * )malloc(sizeof(struct t_node ));
        printf("name = %s\n", temp->name);
        // Assigning value to name variable of temp using arrow operator
        temp->name=n;
        temp->next_dfile=NULL;
        temp->next_file=NULL;

        return temp;
}
```

It's not working to print this `temp->name`, then I tried to print in this way `*temp->name` or like this `&temp->name` and not working. And another question, does this struct return the temp var or a pointer to temp? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the output of this printf call?

Comment: `temp` does not have anything in it there, you just allocated it - have you tried to do the `printf` after the `temp->name=n;` assignment?

Comment: put print function after you assign n to temp->name. and it doesnt return temp itself. it returns what the value (adress) temp pointer holds.

Answer (score 1):

You should print the variable after assigning value to it. This will work,

```
    static struct t_node* create_tnode(char* n) {
        // Assigning memory to struct variable temp
        struct t_node *temp=(struct t_node * )malloc(sizeof(struct t_node ));
                // Assigning value to name variable of temp using arrow operator
        temp->name=n;
        printf("name = %s\n", temp->name);

        temp->next_dfile=NULL;
        temp->next_file=NULL;

        return temp;
}
```